# C++: update variable value inside function in a while loop

Tags: c++11, while-loop, self-modifying

I am not quite expert in C++ and I am writing a program to read multiple URL's on a single line of a html file, so I wrote this code:

```
ifstream bf;
short chapters=0;
string blkhtml;
string blktmpfile; //given
string urldown;    //given
size_t found = 0, limit;

    while(getline(bf, blkhtml)){
            while((blkhtml.find(urldown, found) != string::npos) == 1){
                found = blkhtml.find(urldown);
                limit = blkhtml.find("\"", found);
                found=limit + 1;
                chapters++;
            }
    }
```

My problem here is that found is not updated to be used in the `while` condition. As I've seen, std::string classes aren't updated unless another std::string class (for a string, str.erase() updates it's value, but (str.at() = '') doesn't), What can I do here if I want "found" to be updated every time the loop begins, and for the condition.

What I want to do is:

- Check if there is a coincident expression for the `urldown` given string.
- Set it's first and last character.
- Update 'pos' in the loop after the found url, and then look for the next.

I've looke all over cplusplus.com and cppreference.com and I haven't found something that helps me.

I thought about std::list::remove on a loop with every number from 0 to 9, and then give it a new value, but I don't know if it is the best option.

Comment: You check the condition with `blkhtml.find(urldown, found)`, but you update `found` with `blkhtml.find(urldown)`. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: Yes :) it is because what I am reading is a html file with a very long, single line with all the URL's I am looking for, so I check the condition looking if there is a coincidence with `urldown`, then I use found and limit to go to the end of that url. As limit is the end, `found = limit + 1;` modifies found. Now when `while`begins the starting position has changed after the last coincidence.

Comment: ... but when you update `found`, you are searching from the beginning of the string again, not from where you left off last time. `blkhtml.find(urldown)` doesn't depend on the current value of `found` - it gives you the same position every time through the loop, so you are just running in circles.

Comment: O.o you are right, I will check it, I'm not in my pc right but I'll tell you

Comment: Yes @IgorTandetnik that was the problem, thanks, I checked it right now and it works :) thank you everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you search from beginning each time:

```
while((blkhtml.find(urldown, found) != string::npos) == 1){
    found = blkhtml.find(urldown); // Searches from beginning of the string
```

This should be:

```
while((blkhtml.find(urldown, found) != string::npos) == 1){
    found = blkhtml.find(urldown, found); // Searches from "found"
```

Or, to seach only once, you can put it in the `while` clause:

```
while((found = blkhtml.find(urldown, found)) != string::npos){
```

Also, you don't reset `found` each time a new line is read:

```
while(getline(bf, blkhtml)){
    found = 0;
```

Comment: But I don't need found to be 0, I need it to increase.  Is a single line with "url1,url2,etc" so I find the first, the move to the end of the first, and look for the second, until there are no more matches

Comment: @JorgeBarroso Oh, I see the problem as well

Comment: Thank you, that was right, I was looking from the beginning on an infinite loop, now it's solved :D